# How to mock library function (testing redux action creator)

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, redux

I have example in "*Redux-world*"

I have action creator (simple function):

```
import { v4 } from 'node-uuid';

export const addTodo = (text) => ({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  id: v4(),
  text,
});
```

And I have test for it ([docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html)):

```
import { addTodo } from '../actions'
...
it('should create an action for add todo', () => {
    const text = 'test v4 call'
    const expectedAction = {
      type: 'ADD_TODO',
      text,
      id: 'fake-v4-id', // ???
    }

    expect(addTodo(text).toEqual(expectedAction)
  })
```

Of course, I have different v4 ids:

[image: v4 different ids]

Using v4 in my test directly (change: `id: 'fake-v4-id' -> id: v4()`) - don't solve the problem. Ids will be different.

What I need? Mock, override? Or something else? And how I can do it?

My test framework is Mocha, and assertions library is - Chai.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recipie is:

1. install [babel-plugin-rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-rewire)
2. set test env in *.babelrc* (something, like this)

   {
     "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react", "react-hmre"],
     "env": {
       "test": {
         "plugins": ["rewire"]
       }
     }
   }
3. install babel-cli (if you haven't already)
4. Type test command in your package.json like this:

   NODE_ENV=test babel-node node_modules/.bin/_mocha -r --recursive

* why _mocha? ([link for issue](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/436))

Ok, settings are ready. Now edit test file:

```
import { __RewireAPI__, addTodo } from '../actions'
...
describe('Todo actions', () => {

  before(() => {
    __RewireAPI__.__Rewire__('v4', () => 'fake-v4-id')
  })

  it('should create an action for add todo', () => {
    const text = 'test v4 call'
    const expectedAction = {
      type: 'ADD_TODO',
      text,
      id: 'fake-v4-id',
    }

    expect(addTodo(text)).toEqual(expectedAction)
  })

})
```

Run `npm test`

Comment: Shouldn't that example include a `after` which calls `ComponentToTest.__ResetDependency__('v4');`?

Comment: @machineghost, hm... may be. Looks greate, but I can't know about this.